# login JavaScript - password encode

Tags: javascript, passwords, sha1, password-protection, login-script

I'm just trying to make a simple Login-example in HTML/js.
Of course I will export the password into a database. But for a simple test I tried these:

```js
function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
var cryptpwd = CryptoJS.SHA1(pwd);

alert(cryptpwd);
if (username === "Paili" && cryptpwd === "a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3"){
alert("Login sucess!");
alert(cryptpwd);
window.location = "seite1.html";

return false;
}
else{
alert("something went wrong");
prompt(username,cryptpwd);
return false;
}
}
```

It always goes into ELSE but my output of cryptpwd and username is correct.
Than I query not cryptpwd but pwd and it worked.

Output:

[image]

Why does it not work?

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof cryptpwd);` and `console.log(typeof username);` - if type is != than string, this is the key.

Answer (score -2):

Try using operator == or debug cryptpwd and username to see what's wrong

Comment: Downvote isn' from me....You need 125 repuation...but for now I wish I could give you a downvote @Cutaraca